# ¿Como puedo mostrar una fecha seleccionada en un div?

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas tengo esto en mi javascript

```js
$('.fe_registro').on('click',function(){
      var res = $('.fe_registro').val();
      document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = res;
      console.log(res);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" value="" name="fe_registro" class="fe_registro" id="fe_registro">
    
    <div id="resultado"></div>
```

Lo que quiero es que cuando seleccione una fecha, me lo despliegue en el div pero no se que hago mal, en la consola si me lo muestra pero una vez que le de click, pero lo que quiero es que en cuanto selecciono la fecha me la despliegue

Comment: Pero ¿dónde seleccionas la fecha, en un `select  ... option`?  Muestra el HTML donde seleccionas.

Comment: En el input type date

Comment: Juan, el problema es el evento que has elegido. Es mejor el evento `change` que se lanza cuando el valor del `input date` cambia

Comment: Como ya se ha dicho, es mejor usar un evento más específico como `change`. Pero hay más cosas que yo cambiaría, por ejemplo, un selector por el id y no por la clase, poniendo esto: `$( "#fe_registro" )`  y... realmente tu `input` no obliga a escribir una fecha válida, puede el usuario escribir cualquier cosa allí, prueba a escribir: `kkkkk`.

Comment: @A.Cedano no me deja introducir "kkk" ni semejante. Solo fechas

Comment: no deja escribir pero si pongo varios números si pero en el año, permite hasta 6

Comment: A mí si me deja @lois6b probando el fragmento de código in situ. Estoy trabajando con Safari.

Comment: @A.Cedano eso lo explica. input date no se comporta bien en safari. prueba firefox o chrome

Comment: @lois6b el problema no es que yo cambie a otro navegador, sino que su código posiblemente lo usará mucha gente con Safari, como yo y no puedes obligarles a cambiar de navegador para que el código funcione. Además, usar `innerHTML` es peligroso. Si yo pruebo el snippet poniendo esto: `2018-11-12 <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_ES/ES/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif">` sale en el div mi botón de donación de PayPal. Y pueden ocurrir más cosas graves como ataques XSS.

Comment: @A.Cedano si, tienes razón a la hora de mencionar la compatibilidad de navegadores

Comment: @A.Cedano a mi cuando lo pongo a mi me aparec un error
GET http........(la urla) y despues net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: Parece que tu cliente tiene alguna protección contra XSS, pero no todos los clientes la tendrán, supongo.

Comment: Bueno entonces ¿no tendría que preocuparme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de usar `click` usa `change` asi:

```js
$('.fe_registro').on('change',function(){
      var res = $('.fe_registro').val();
      document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = res;
      console.log(res);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" value="" name="fe_registro" class="fe_registro" id="fe_registro">
    
    <div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: No me despliega el resultado en el div

Comment: Aqui si funciona cuando escoges una fecha.

Comment: Alan `innerHTML` no es seguro. Puedo promocionar mi botón de donaciones de PayPal en el sitio poniendo por ejemplo: `2018-11-12 <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_ES/ES/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif">` Es una puerta abierta a ataques XSS.

Comment: Tienes razon, podria usar `.textContent` en lugar de `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Investigare la diferencia de uno y otro